# WooCommerce: Change the label of the “Return to shop” button in the empty cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label

I would like to change the text in the "return to shop" button in the empty cart page in WooCommerce

I found in this snippet:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
?>
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if (jQuery('a.button.wc-backward'))
        jQuery('a.button.wc-backward').text("My Text");
});
</script>
<?php
});
```

---

it's working just for the empty cart page but not in the empty cart page after i remove an item, i mean when appear the notice of the removed item the button still "`retun to shop`" and not my custom text..

Any suggestion to make it work in every condition?

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce **4.6** added some new filters and actions:

One of them:

`woocommerce_return_to_shop_text` - Filter to change the label of the “Return to shop” button in the empty cart page.

So you get

```php
/**
 * Filter "Return To Shop" text.
 *
 * @since 4.6.0
 * @param string $default_text Default text.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_return_to_shop_text ( $default_text ) {
    // Add new text
    $default_text = __( 'My new text', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $default_text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_text', 'filter_woocommerce_return_to_shop_text', 10, 1 );
```